Issue in telegram bot
I need this bot to be able to send alerts, messages, etc., to all users who are using it or have started using it, but it sends this only for first user, who start the bot in the telegram.
And bot can't process requests from other users while it's running for another.And if the bot is launched (in telegram itself), and another user also wants to use it, and launches it, then it stops working for both users. It is the program itself on Python that continues to work, but the Telegram bot does not send anything to anyone else.
I don't know much about python (but I need it for a university project), so don't criticize too much. I tried to use asyncio library, but it has many inflicts and issues, and I decide to stop this idea.
My telegram bot running
This is my friends attempt to run my bot
from alerts_in_ua import Client as AlertsClient
import telebot
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

# Визначення поточного дня та часу
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%A")

# Open the database connection
conn = sqlite3.connect('schedule.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Перевірка наявності таблиці 'schedule' та її створення, якщо не існує
cur.execute('''SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='schedule' ''')
if cur.fetchone()[0] == 1:
    print('Таблиця "schedule" вже існує.')
else:
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE schedule (
               day TEXT,
               start_time TEXT,
               end_time TEXT,
               subject TEXT
               )''')
    print('Таблиця "schedule" успішно створена.')

# Дані для додавання до таблиці розкладу
schedule_data = [
    ('Monday', '08:30', '09:50', 'Програмування'),
    ('Monday', '10:10', '11:30', 'Вища математика'),
    ('Monday', '11:50', '13:10', 'Іноземна мова'),
    ('Monday', '13:30', '14:50', 'Інформаційні технології'),
    ('Tuesday', '08:30', '09:50', 'Інформаційні технології'),
    ('Tuesday', '10:10', '11:30', 'Програмування'),
    ('Tuesday', '11:50', '13:10', 'Вища математика'),
    ('Tuesday', '19:50', '23:00', 'Вища математика'),
    ('Wednesday', '11:50', '13:10', 'Фізкультура'),
    ('Wednesday', '13:30', '14:50', 'Вища математика'),
    ('Wednesday', '15:10', '16:30', 'Вища математика'),
    ('Thursday', '13:00', '14:30', 'Групова динаміка або Правова культура особистості'),
    ('Thursday', '13:00', '14:30', 'Лінійна алгебра'),
    ('Friday', '08:30', '09:50', 'Лінійна алгебра'),
    ('Friday', '10:10', '11:30', 'Лінійна алгебра'),
    ('Friday', '11:50', '13:10', 'Правова культура особистості'),
]
# Додавання даних до таблиці
for data in schedule_data:
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO schedule (day, start_time, end_time, subject) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)''', data)

# Збереження змін у базі даних
conn.commit()


# Функція для додавання даних до таблиці розкладу
def add_class_to_schedule(day, start_time, end_time, subject):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('schedule.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO schedule (day, start_time, end_time, subject) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)''',
                    (day, start_time, end_time, subject))
        conn.commit()
        print(f"Додано новий запис до таблиці розкладу: {day}, {start_time} - {end_time}, {subject}")
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Помилка при додаванні запису до таблиці розкладу:", e)
    finally:
        conn.close()


# Визначення поточного дня та часу
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%A")

# Дані для додавання до таблиці розкладу
new_schedule_data = [

]
# Додавання нових даних до таблиці
for data in new_schedule_data:
    add_class_to_schedule(*data)

    # Вибірка та виведення рядків з бази даних
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE day=?', (current_day,))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)


# Функція для визначення наступної пари за часом
def next_class_info(message):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('schedule.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()

        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")  # Convert to string
        current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%A")  # Current day of the week

        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE day=? AND start_time>=? ORDER BY start_time ASC LIMIT 1',
                    (current_day, current_time))
        next_class_info = cur.fetchone()

        conn.close()

        return next_class_info
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Помилка при отриманні наступної пари:", e)


# Функція для перевірки, чи йде зараз пара
def is_class_now(message):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('schedule.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()

        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")  # Convert to string
        current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%A")  # Current day of the week

        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE day=? AND start_time<=? AND end_time>=?', (current_day, current_time, current_time))
        class_info = cur.fetchone()

        conn.close()

        return class_info  # Повертаємо всю інформацію про поточну пару
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Помилка при перевірці пари:", e)



# Функція для надсилання повідомлення про наступну пару
def notify_next_class(message):
    next_class = next_class_info(message)
    if next_class:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Наступна пара: {next_class[4]} об {next_class[2]} до {next_class[3]}")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "На сьогодні пар більше немає.")

# Функція для надсилання повідомлення про завершену пару
def notify_finished_class(message):
    current_class = is_class_now(message)
    if current_class:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Поточна пара: {current_class[4]} - {current_class[2]} до {current_class[3]}")


load_dotenv()

# Отримуємо токен бота з оточення
BOT_TOKEN = os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN')

# Ініціалізуємо бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

# Видаляємо webhook, якщо він встановлений
bot.remove_webhook()

# Ініціалізуємо клієнт для отримання тривог
alerts_client = AlertsClient(token="9436aac57170ca86e55a7c054a168578afcb412dab2203")

# Змінна для зберігання вже відправлених тривог
sent_alerts = set()
# Затримка між кожним запитом до API (в секундах)
API_REQUEST_DELAY = 8


# Функція для отримання активних тривог
def get_active_alerts(message):
    regions_status = alerts_client.get_air_raid_alert_statuses_by_oblast()
    time.sleep(API_REQUEST_DELAY)

    return set(str(region) for region in regions_status.get_active_alert_oblasts())


# Функція для сповіщення про активні тривоги, наступну та закінчену пари
def notify_active_alerts(message):
    global sent_alerts
    active_alerts = get_active_alerts(message)

    # Viznachaemo novi tryvohy, yaki shche ne buli vidpravleni
    new_alerts = active_alerts - sent_alerts

    # Viznachaemo zakryti tryvohy, yaki buli vidpravleni ranishe
    closed_alerts = sent_alerts - active_alerts

    if new_alerts:
        for region in new_alerts:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Повітряна тривога в {region.split(':')[1].strip()}! \n")  # Zelenyy kruzhochok
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пройдіть в найближче укриття!")  # Додано повідомлення про укриття
            # Відправка повідомлення про наступну та закінчену пару, якщо є нові тривоги
            notify_next_class(message)
            notify_finished_class(message)

    if closed_alerts:
        for region in closed_alerts:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Тривога в {region.split(':')[1].strip()} припинена!\n")  # Chervonyy kruzhochok
            # Відправка повідомлення про наступну та закінчену пару, якщо є закриті тривоги
            notify_next_class(message)
            notify_finished_class(message)

    # Oновlyuyemo zminnu z vidpravlenymy tryvohamy
    sent_alerts = active_alerts



# Обробник команди /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    global running
    if not running:
        running = True
        bot.reply_to(message, "Бот почав відправляти тривоги.")

        # Створення нового з'єднання з базою даних
        conn = sqlite3.connect('schedule.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()

        # Перевірка наявності даних в таблиці розкладу перед їх додаванням
        cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schedule")
        count = cur.fetchone()[0]
        if count == 0:
            # Додавання даних до таблиці, якщо вона порожня
            for data in schedule_data:
                cur.execute('''INSERT INTO schedule (day, start_time, end_time, subject) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)''', data)
            conn.commit()
            print("Дані розкладу додано до таблиці.")
        else:
            print("Дані розкладу вже присутні в таблиці.")

        # Закриття з'єднання з базою даних
        conn.close()

        # Запуск циклу перевірки тривог
        while running:
            notify_active_alerts(message)


# Обробник команди /stop
@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
def stop(message):
    global running
    running = False
    bot.reply_to(message, "Бот припинив відправляти тривоги.")

    # Створення нового з'єднання з базою даних
    conn = sqlite3.connect('schedule.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    try:
        # Очищення таблиці розкладу
        cur.execute("DELETE FROM schedule")
        conn.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Таблиця розкладу очищена.")
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Помилка при очищенні таблиці розкладу:", e)
    finally:
        # Закриття з'єднання з базою даних
        conn.close()


# Обробник всіх повідомлень
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)


# Інтервал перевірки наявності тривог (в секундах)
CHECK_INTERVAL = 8  # 10 секунд

# Флаг, який показує, чи запущений бот
running = False

# Запускаємо бота
bot.polling()
# Збереження змін у базі даних
conn.commit()
# Закриття з'єднання з базою даних
conn.close()


what is the problem? Do you get error? Show it in question (not in comments)? Do you get wrong result? Show it in question. We can't run your code, we can't see your computer, and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Hi, usually the issue with threading a bot is related to how you host a bot rather than your code. Could you provide info on how you host the bot.
